# Detecting a URL using PHP preg_match that allows the absence of www

Tags: php, url, preg-match

What would be the PHP URL `preg_match` code that allows the absence of the `www.` part of the link?

**Normal preg_match URL code:**

```
%^((https?://)|(www\.))([a-z0-9-].?)+(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$%i
```

**I've tried this:**

```
%^((https?://)|([a-z0-9-].?)+(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$%i
```

Extra background:

This is for an `if` statement that checks a user's input.

```
elseif (!preg_match("%^((https?://)|(www\.))([a-z0-9-].?)+(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$%i",$link)){
   $linkErr = "Please enter a valid URL.";
}
```

Comment: Have a look at : http://php.net/parse_url

Comment: If u want to redirect users from non-www to www u could use .htaccess. See http://dense13.com/blog/2008/02/27/redirecting-non-www-to-www-with-htaccess/

Answer (score 1):

You match either https?:// or www. Why can't there be both?

Not tested and just written down:

```
^(https?://)?(www\.)?[a-z]+\.[a-z]{2,3}(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$

 https://     www.   google . com       :1234    /blabla.php?foo=bar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function hasWww($url) {
   $data = parse_url($url);
   if (isset($data['host'])) return strpos($data['host'], 'www.') === 0;
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert a **?** between ')('. 
Try that:

```
preg_match("%^((https?://)|(www\.))?([a-z0-9-].?)+(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$%i", $link);
```